# What is this symbol "Dy" called (see image)

Tags: meaning, symbols

I got a card and there's a symbol which precedes "James".  Something like "from" or "love".  Does anyone know what this symbol is?

[image: what is this symbol called]

Comment: It looks like an ampersand to me (&).

Comment: I have seen many tries at the &-sign, but this one is... original.

Comment: @oerkelens  I've updated with the full picture for context

Comment: @oerkelens: and now that I can see the whole message,  there appears to be another (slightly less original) &-sign later in the message that looks nothing like the first symbol. It's difficult to imagine that they're two different attempts at the &-sign by the same person.

Comment: Maybe it's a heart?

Comment: I suspect it's just a stylized "X".

Comment: surely the sender could answer this one

Comment: I could see those strokes making a heart if the card hadn't slipped.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a stylised "fr", standing for "from", a common term used when signing a card.

The initial upstroke, downstroke and curve form a cursive lower-case 'f', and the remaining piece that looks like a '7' forms a cursive 'r'.

Comment: It's certainly possible.  Especially if you look at the r in your.

Answer (score 1):

It's a heart.  She is signing their names but instead of writing "Love," for the closing, she drew a heart.